# Google OAuth2 not working with React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, google-api-js-client

Could someone please help me figure out why my Google OAuth is not working with my App? I am running the exact same code with a different App I have built in the past and it seems to Log in and Out smooth on that one but not with the App I am currently working with. I don't even seem to see the log in button unless I remove the mapStateToProps function entirely. In which case the button appears but is obviously not working as intended. Any ideas? I am using Redux and action creators and reducers to reflect whether or not the user has signed in.

```
GoogleOath.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../actions';

class GoogleAuth extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            window.gapi.client.init({
                clientId: '//// hidden ',
                scope: 'email'

            }).then(() => {
              this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

              this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
              this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
            });
        });
    }

    onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
     if (isSignedIn) {
         this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
     } else {
         this.props.signOut();
     }
    };

    onSignIn = () => {
     this.auth.signIn();
    };

    onSignOut = () => {
     this.auth.signOut();
    };

    renderAuthButton() {
        if (this.props.isSignedIn === null) {
            return null;
        } else if (this.props.isSignedIn) {
            return (
                <button onClick={this.onSignOut} className='waves-effect waves-light social-icon btn google'>
                <i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign out</button>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <button onClick={this.onSignIn} className='waves-effect waves-light social-icon btn google'>
                <i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign in</button>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.renderAuthButton()}</div>
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { signIn, signOut }
)(GoogleAuth);
```

```
Actions Index.js

import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from './types';

export const signIn = (userId) => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN,
        payload: userId
    };
};

export const signOut = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_OUT
    }
};
```

```
Reducers Index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer
});
```

```
Reducers authReducer.js

import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isSignedIn: null,
  userId: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case SIGN_IN:
        return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
      case SIGN_OUT:
        return { ...state, IsSignedIn: false, userId: null };
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `init` method fails then you will always just have a blank screen.  The initial value of `state.auth.isSignedIn` is `null` and your render says to return `null` in this case.  So you need `isSignedIn` to become a `boolean`.

Working backwards, `isSignedIn` will be set from an action dispatched in `onAuthChange`, which is called as a listener on `this.auth.isSignedIn`.  That listener and `this.auth` are both set in the `.then()` callback.  That callback will only be called if `window.gapi.client.init()` succeeds.

You can add a `.catch(console.error)` callback to see what your problem is.  The failure case could be handled better in your UI but ultimately you want to be getting a valid auth instance!

Comment: Hi Linda, Thank you so much for such a detailed reply. I have rebuilt this entire component from scratch and actually got it working now hehe. All the best!